# How to limit the number of properties EF has gen'd when used as a lookup

Tags: .net, entity-framework

If I wanted to return just the ID, and Name from a collection of Customer entities, what would be the recommended way of doing this? Should I use the Entity Set and then pick off what I need as I loop the collection? Is there LINQ syntax that can give me the equivalent of a SQL Select clause (i.e. Select ID, Name From Customer).

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**Queryable.Select`<TSource, TResult`>**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx) to project the collection:

```
var customers = ctx
   .Customers
   .Where(x => x.FirstName == "Joe")
   .Select(x => new { ID = x.CustomerId, Name = x.CustomerName })
   .ToList();
```

Note that will project the results into a `List<T>` of anonymous types.

If you want to project it into something else (e.g custom class/POCO), you'll need to materalize the result set **first**, and **then** project the query (e.g `.ToList()` and then `.Select()`).

In other words, if you do this:

```
var customers = ctx
       .Customers
       .Where(x => x.FirstName == "Joe")
       .Select(x => new CutDownCustomer { ID = x.CustomerId, Name = x.CustomerName })
       .ToList(); // fire query
```

You will get an EF error (cannot be translated to Linq-Entities query - as "CutDownCustomer" is not part of the conceptual model).

So you must do this:

```
var customers = ctx
       .Customers
       .Where(x => x.FirstName == "Joe")
       .ToList() // fire query
       .Select(x => new CutDownCustomer { ID = x.CustomerId, Name = x.CustomerName });
```

Of course, if you only require method scope for your result set, anonymous types should be sufficient.

HTH.